# MySite Filenot found error while creating?

Tags: sharepoint, mysite

for one user mysite created wrong ( for all others creating mysites are creating fine). While creating mysite it throws an error 400 (Bad request).

I try to delete site using below command. Its throwing error.

```
stsadm -o deletesite -url "http://mysite/personal/0011585"
```

error:

```
The system cannot find the path specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070003)
```

Even I tried to delete site from SSP. (Manage Personl site)

```
File Not Found.   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.OpenWebInternal(String bstrUrl, Guid& pguidID, String& pbstrRequestAccessEmail, UInt32& pwebVersion, String& 
pbstrServerRelativeUrl, UInt32& pnLanguage, UInt32& pnLocale, String& pbstrDefaultTheme, String& pbstrDefaultThemeCSSUrl, String& pbstrAlternateCSSUrl, String& pbstrCustomizedCssFileList, String& pbstrCustomJSUrl, String& pbstrAlternateHeaderUrl, String& pbstrMasterUrl, String& pbstrCustomMasterUrl, String& pbstrSiteLogoUrl, String& pbstrSiteLogoDescription, Object& pvarUser, Boolean& pvarIsAuditor, Int32& plSiteFlags)
```

How should I cleanup this website? and recreat new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you check the user's profile and try to clear the field which stores the URL to user's MySite. SharePoint writes an error message to this field when an error occurred during the MySite creation process. As long as this error message is in the field every try to recreate the MySite will fail.

I'm not sure if this will solve you problem, but you can give it a try.